# working out percentage - MySQL sum from alias unknown column

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get the query to output the percentage by dividing the Correct SUM field with  the count field and it is returning an unknown column name error:

```
SELECT Q.*, (Correct/total) AS percent 
FROM 
(SELECT Q.firstname, SUM(CASE WHEN Q.response != Q.answer THEN 1 END) AS Incorrect, SUM(CASE WHEN Q.response = Q.answer THEN 1 END) AS Correct, COUNT(Q.Quiz_question_id) as total 
FROM (SELECT User_Accounts_.user_id, User_Accounts_.firstname, User_Accounts_.lastname, Quiz.quiz_id AS Quiz_id2, Quiz.quiz_title, Quiz_Assign.quiz_assign_id, Quiz_Assign.quiz_id AS Quiz_id1, Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id AS QQID, Quiz_Questions.quiz_id, Quiz_Questions.question, Quiz_Questions.option1, Quiz_Questions.option2, Quiz_Questions.option3, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_question_id, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.response, Quiz_Questions.answer, Class_List.Class_List_id AS CLID, Quiz_Assign.class_list_id 
FROM User_Accounts_, Class_List, Quiz, Quiz_Assign, Quiz_Questions, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question WHERE (Quiz.quiz_id=Quiz_Assign.quiz_id) AND (Quiz_Questions.quiz_id=Quiz.quiz_id) AND (Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id=Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_question_id) AND (Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_assign_id=Quiz_Assign.quiz_assign_id) AND (Class_List.Class_List_id=Quiz_Assign.class_list_id) AND (Quiz_Assign.quiz_id=16) AND (Class_List.class_id=29) AND (User_Accounts_.user_id=Class_List.user_id)) AS Q;
```

Comment: Please reformat your sql query. Also -for next time- add an appropiate tag to your question- wich relating to used rmdbs.

Comment: Your brackets don't match up you need another closing bracket after as q (with another alias(

Answer (score 0):

Your query has issue with its subquery's use of derived data. In MySQL, you cannot use an alias from a subquery in the same level where it's being created. This means that your calculation for percent is not able to find the Correct and total columns in the same level where they are defined. To fix this, you need to add one more level of subquery:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    (T.Correct/T.total) AS percent 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        Q.firstname, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Q.response != Q.answer THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Incorrect,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Q.response = Q.answer THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Correct, 
        COUNT(Q.Quiz_question_id) as total 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            User_Accounts_.user_id, 
            User_Accounts_.firstname, 
            User_Accounts_.lastname, 
            Quiz.quiz_id AS Quiz_id2, 
            Quiz.quiz_title, 
            Quiz_Assign.quiz_assign_id, 
            Quiz_Assign.quiz_id AS Quiz_id1, 
            Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id AS QQID, 
            Quiz_Questions.quiz_id, 
            Quiz_Questions.question, 
            Quiz_Questions.option1, 
            Quiz_Questions.option2, 
            Quiz_Questions.option3, 
            Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_question_id, 
            Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.response, 
            Quiz_Questions.answer, 
            Class_List.Class_List_id AS CLID, 
            Quiz_Assign.class_list_id 
        FROM 
            User_Accounts_, Class_List, Quiz, Quiz_Assign, Quiz_Questions, Quiz_Assign_Student_Question 
        WHERE 
            (Quiz.quiz_id=Quiz_Assign.quiz_id) AND 
            (Quiz_Questions.quiz_id=Quiz.quiz_id) AND 
            (Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id=Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_question_id) AND 
            (Quiz_Assign_Student_Question.quiz_assign_id=Quiz_Assign.quiz_assign_id) AND 
            (Class_List.Class_List_id=Quiz_Assign.class_list_id) AND 
            (Quiz_Assign.quiz_id=16) AND 
            (Class_List.class_id=29) AND 
            (User_Accounts_.user_id=Class_List.user_id)
        ) AS Q
    GROUP BY
        Q.firstname
    ) AS T
```